# Issue with configuring multiple environments for ZF2 application on same virtual machine

Tags: php, apache, centos, zend-framework2

I have ZF2 application on very old virtual machine with CentOS 5, Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4. I've tried to setup different environment on the same VM. 
So, we have:

1) 3 folders:

```
/var/www/html/dev

/var/www/html/qa

/var/www/html/prod
```

with pretty much the same source code (different branches of git repository).

2) 3 subdomains:

```
dev.<mysite>.com

qa.<mysite>.com

<mysite>.com
```

3) httpd.conf with:

```
................

NameVirtualHost *:80

.................

<VirtualHost *:80>

     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/public

     ServerName dev.<mysite>.com

     ........................
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/qa/public

    ServerName qa.<mysite>.com

    ........................

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/prod/public

    ServerName <mysite>.com
    ........................
</VirtualHost>
........................
```

To make sure it works I added two lines of code to Home\Index view of each folder.

For dev:

```
....
echo "DEV";
echo $ZF2_PATH;
....
```

For qa:

```
.... 
echo "QA";
echo $ZF2_PATH;
....
```

For prod:

```
....
echo "PROD";
echo $ZF2_PATH;
....
```

After restart httpd service:

- if I do first call to qa..com then on each environment I'll see:

  on dev:

  **QA**

  /var/www/html/**dev**/vendor/....

  on qa:

  **QA**

  /var/www/html/**qa**/vendor/....

  on prod:

  **QA**

  /var/www/html/**prod**/vendor/....
- if I do first call to dev..com then on each environment I'll see:

  on dev:

  **DEV**

  /var/www/html/**dev**/vendor/...

  on qa:

  **DEV**

  /var/www/html/**qa**/vendor/....

  on prod:

  **DEV**

  /var/www/html/**prod**/vendor/....

It is not that I expected. I want to see different hardocde on each enviroment evrytime. I tired to reproduce it on my local computer (Windows + Apache 2.4) and could not do it.

Does anybody know what could be issue with my config?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `Virtual Host` configuration first by type this command

```
apachectl -S
```

It will display `VirtualHost configuration:` with `hostname` and where is the configuration file including the line number too.

By know the information you will know your configuration correct or not

Comment: I see this:  
*:80 is a NameVirtualHost  
default server dev.<mysite>.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:995)  
port 80 namevhost dev.<mysite>.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:995)  
port 80 namevhost qa.<mysite>.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1002)  
port 80 namevhost www.<mysite>.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1015)  
alias www.<mysite>.com  
alias <mysite>.com  
port 80 namevhost stable.<mysite>.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1059)

Comment: Looks like the reason of this behaviour is Zend OpCache